# When will Spring Data Elasticsearch support server version 7.1?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

when spring-data-elasticsearch plan maintain 7.1.1 version ?

Get error:

org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate.doCount(ElasticsearchTemplate.java:549)

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to track [this ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAES-585) for progress on that topic.